# Serverless: sqs:CreateQueue Access ... denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, serverless-framework

I'm trying to deploy my Serverless Framework application to multiple stages.

I created an IAM user with all the permissions I need and placed their access-key in `~/.aws/credentials`.

When I deploy to stage `beta`, the deploy works perfectly:

```sh
sls deploy -s beta --verbose --profile myProfile
```

When I deploy to stage `dev`, I get an access-denied error. This command:

```
sls deploy -s dev --verbose --profile myProfile
```

Generates these errors:

```
CloudFormation - UPDATE_FAILED - AWS::SQS::Queue - MyQueue
CloudFormation - CREATE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::SNS::Topic - MyTopic
CloudFormation - UPDATE_FAILED - AWS::SNS::Topic - MyTopic
CloudFormation - UPDATE_FAILED - AWS::IAM::Role - IamRoleLambdaExecution
...
Serverless Error ---------------------------------------

  An error occurred: MyQueue - API: sqs:CreateQueue Access to the resource https://sqs.xx-xxxx-2.amazonaws.com/ is denied..
```

My `serverless.yml` looks like this:

```yaml
# serverless.yml

service: "my-lambda"
app: "my-lambda"
org: "my-org"

package:
  individually: true

custom:
  topicName: "my-topic--${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}"
  queueName: "my-queue--${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}"

provider:
  name: "aws"
  runtime: "nodejs12.x"
  region: "xx-xxxx-2"
  profile: "myProfile"
  environment:
    NODE_ENV: "${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}"
    SNS_TOPIC_NAME: "${self:custom.topicName}"
    SQS_QUEUE_NAME: "${self:custom.queueName}"
    SLS_DEBUG: "*"

functions:
  myFunc:
    handler: "index.handler"
    events:
      - sns:
          arn: !Ref MyTopic
          topicName: "${self:custom.topicName}"
          redrivePolicy:
            deadLetterTargetRef: "MyQueue"

resources:
  Resources:
    MyTopic:
      Type: "AWS::SNS::Topic"
      Properties:
        TopicName: "${self:custom.topicName}"
    MyQueue:
      Type: "AWS::SQS::Queue"
      Properties:
        QueueName: "${self:custom.queueName}"
```

Here's the policy for `myProfile`:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ssm:GetParameters",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ssm:xx-xxxx-2::parameter/Config/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sns:SetSubscriptionAttributes",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sns:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:xx-xxxx-2::my-topic"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sqs:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:xx-xxxx-2::my-queue"
        }
    ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you provided access to create sqs on both stages or only beta. As per your template you need to give create access on "my-queue--beta" as well as "my-queue--dev". From the error it seems you have only granted for "my-queue--beta"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you folks, but the problem ended up being very simple. In `serverless.yml`, I defined my topic and queue names like this:

```yaml
custom:
  topicName: "my-topic--${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}"
  queueName: "my-queue--${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}"
```

But in my policy I wrote `arn:aws:sns:xx-xxxx-2::my-topic` and `arn:aws:sqs:xx-xxxx-2::my-queue`.

The solution was as simple as adding `--stage` suffixes to the resources in my policy, or using `*` for the trailing segment of the ARN.

Thank you for your responses, all.

Answer (score 1):

It's your AWS user profile policy issue.

> ```yaml
> resources:   
>  Resources:
>     MyTopic:
>       Type: "AWS::SNS::Topic"
>       Properties:
>         TopicName: "${self:custom.topicName}"
>     MyQueue:
>       Type: "AWS::SQS::Queue"
>       Properties:
>         QueueName: "${self:custom.queueName}"
> ```

**sls deploy** on run, try to create all the resources defined under resources of serverless.yml config.

Even if you provide administrator access to profile, it will not work.
As you've mentioned in profile policy, it seems like you have already created the queue and topic.

By defining them under resources of serverless.yml simply specifying that you want to create those resources again.

As you have no admin access right now, it shows you have no access to create sqs queue.

Try to add administrator role in your aws profile, you'll see error again that queue and topic are already exist.

Try **to delete** already existing resources and then **sls deploy**, It'll work.
or simply do not use resources and specify ARN directly.

```yaml
functions:
 myFunc:
   handler: index.handler
   events:
      - sns:
          arn: arn:xxx
          redrivePolicy:
            deadLetterTargetArn: arn:aws:sqs:xxx:DLQ
```

Refer to this
https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/3183

Answer (score 0):

```
I created an IAM user with all the permissions I need and placed their access-key in ~/.aws/credentials.
```

Please verify the user you created has permissions to create SQS queues -
CloudFormation is telling you that it doesn't. If you have multiple AWS roles configured, please ensure the environment variable `AWS_PROFILE` is set to the correct role.

If you still are experiencing this error, please post the entire IAM policy.